# MarkLogic: The size limit for inferred triples in a ruleset store has been exceeded

Tags: performance, marklogic, inference

I have defined a set of inference rules, and loaded 1.2M triples into MarkLogic. When trying to run a SPARQL query, I am getting this error:
[1.0-ml] XDMP-INFFULL: ?ANON1356348214865319439 -- The size limit for inferred triples in a ruleset store has been exceeded

Is there a size limit for the inferred triples, or does it really depend on the host machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase this in a few ways. Basic info and options are briefly described here: https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/messages/XDMP-en/XDMP-INFFULL

Comment: Thank David. I have done that, and with values of 70000 for "max inference size" I am still getting the same error. Is there a hard limit at all?